# How to convert an ELF executable to C code? The generated C code need not be human-readable

Tags: c, linux, transform, elf

I have an ELF file that I would like to decompile into `C` code, and make simple changes to the resulting `C` code and rebuild it into an ELF.

The decompiled `C` code need not be fully human readable. Eg, if variables and function names come out obfuscated, it is okay.

Which tools can I use to accomplish this on Linux?

PS: If decompiling to `C` is not possible or is not easy, I'm willing to consider decompiling to assembly language, though tweaking the assembly source will be very difficult for me.

**UPDATE:** You may assume that I'm using the following `C` program to get my `a.out` ELF. Now, assume further that I've lost this original `C` source. So, I would now like to decompile it to (a possibly obfuscated) `C` source in which I'm at least able to change small things like the strings `"world"`, `"Hello"`, and `"Bye"`, or be able to reverse the sense of the `if` statement, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[256];

const char *Hello = "Hello";
const char *Bye = "Bye";
const char *Who = "world";

char * greet(const char *greeting, const char *str) {
    strcpy(buf, greeting);
    strcat(buf, ", ");
    strcat(buf, str);
    strcat(buf, "!");
    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sayHello = 0;

    if(sayHello) {
        printf("%s\n", greet(Hello, Who));
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", greet(Bye, Who));
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. It is impossible. an optimized ELF image has lost information w.r.t. the original C source.

Comment: What is your ELF file and how did you get it?

Comment: Please see the **Update** above.

Comment: Compile your example with `gcc -Wall -O3 -S -fverbose-asm myhello.c` and look inside the produced `myhello.s`

Comment: Why do you ask? There might be other ways to achieve your goals (`LD_PRELOAD` tricks perhaps). Please explain what you really want to do.

Comment: What I really want to do is, given any arbitrary ELF program for which I do not have the source, I want to be able to do trivial reverse engineering tasks like, say, changing menu-option strings, window and dialog, titles, etc. Now, I hope you won't ask me 'why' I want to do all of this. So far, I'm quite shocked though that the `a.out` doesn't even have my constant strings in it: if they aren't there, then where the heck are they?

Comment: In general, faithful **decompilation is impossible**: the compilation process is losing information from the source file, and in general you cannot recover it. This is why *free software* is so useful and important: you keep the *freedom* to improve it!

Comment: You could use the `strings` utility to find some strings in an executable, but the compiler might have removed them...

Comment: *"... but the compiler might have removed them"* But removed **where**, and **why**? I can understand it folding duplicate constant strings into a single string instance, but other than that, I doubt if it would bend over backwards to hide/obfuscate/encrypt/compress something as fundamental as a character string. I can understand it doing various stunts with code/logic, but string constant data...? I'm quite taken aback to say the least. Btw, thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: For instance, the compiler could optimize `!strcmp(s,"ab")` into `(s[0]=='a' && s[1]=='b' && !s[2])` so the `"ab"` string is not in the binary. Likewise, some `printf` with a constant format string may be optimized.

Comment: As I said, it's string **constant** data. I may not be invoking any function calls over these constant strings, so why would the compiler break strings apart in anticipation? Plus, `strcmp` is a library function and not a language primitive, so I doubt if the compiler would go to such lengths, namely, of storing intelligence inside of itself as to what `strcmp` and other string functions of the C library do internally. Am I right?

Comment: GCC knows `printf` and `strcmp` See http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: Not to nit-pick (in fact, thanks for this side info!), but I'm not using any `strcmp` but rather wholesale copy operations with string  for which I cannot think of any optimizations along the lines you suggested above. Even in the gcc link you provided, I can see `.string "hello world\n"` clearly sitting in there. That's what I too would expect of my program.

Comment: Tool requests are off-topic here.

Answer (score 12):

This will give you (almost) an assembly code translation:

```
objdump --disassemble <elf file>
```

I say almost because the output contains some annotations like binary file position markers and can't serve directly as input to an assembler, but it's close.

Comment: I noticed that some strings (`const char *`'s) -- which I know exist in the ELF -- are missing from the output. Also, how do recompile the output of `objdump` to get another ELF?

Comment: objdump can't reverse reloctions, so it's nowhere near complete for this purpose.

Comment: @Harry: I'm pretty sure your strings are still there.You have to disassemble with `-D` and most likely your strings will get misinterpreted as instructions. To reassembly into an ELF you can pass the assembly to GCC.

Answer (score 3):

You write a simulator for the processor, then you run the elf instructions through your simulated processor. It's generally not too much of a task because even CISC processors have relatively small, contained instruction sets that perform simple operations.

When you've got that working, look at more efficient solutions, like outputting C code to match instructions.